# Crop transparent part of the image after snaping visible part of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, cgcontext

I have UIScrollView with UIImageView on it. You can zoom it and crop visible part.

Here is my code for snap:

```
    UIImage *visibleScrollImage = nil;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.scrollView.bounds.size, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    {
        CGPoint offset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
        CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), -offset.x, -offset.y);
        [self.scrollView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        visibleScrollImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    eivc.editImage = visibleScrollImage;
```

When image doesn't take all visible part of UIScrollView, I don't understand how to snap image without transparent part of UIImageView. I tried to guess with different sizes for context and offset coordinates, but it didn't work out because i obviously don't understand something about images, scrollview or/and CGContext.

Here are some examples, i set backgroundColor red for visibility.

[image: What i get right now]

[image: What i want]

**Edit:**

Right now i made half solution
I set imageView.frame like this

```
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        CGFloat initialImageHeight = result.size.height;
        CGFloat initialImageWidth = result.size.width;
        CGFloat height = self.scrollView.bounds.size.height;
        CGFloat width = self.scrollView.bounds.size.width;
        CGFloat frameHeight = height;
        CGFloat frameWidth = width;

        if ((initialImageHeight / initialImageWidth) > (height / width)) {
            frameHeight = width * initialImageHeight / initialImageWidth;
        } else if ((initialImageHeight / initialImageWidth) < (height / width)) {
            frameWidth = height * initialImageWidth / initialImageHeight;
        }

        self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
        self.imageView.image = result;
```

and I made minimumZoomScale = 1.0

It prevent image to take not full scrollview visible part.

Answer (score 0):

As your description,i guess you demand is such as [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJw0a.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bif94.jpg)

first image is normal ,second image is scaled image. what puzzled you is that to snap image without transparent part of imageView,so when you zoom imageView,imageView's origin and bounds change along with. you can take screen image,then base on imageView's coordinate,caculate a rect which is imageView,take a short image,this image is your imageView's image, code as below.

```
- (UIImage*)cropImage{
    UIImage *screenImage = [UIImage imageFromView:self];
    CGFloat imageViewWidth = self.imageView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat imageViewHeight = self.imageView.frame.size.height;

    CGRect rect;
    UIImage *clipImage;

    if (type == 1) {
        if (imageViewHeight < SCREENWIDTH) {

            rect = CGRectMake(0, SCREENHEIGHT/2-imageViewHeight/2, SCREENWIDTH, imageViewHeight);
        }else{

            rect = CGRectMake(0, SCREENHEIGHT/2-SCREENWIDTH/2, SCREENWIDTH, SCREENWIDTH);
        }
    }else if (type == 2){
        if (imageViewWidth < SCREENWIDTH) {
            rect = CGRectMake(SCREENWIDTH/2-imageViewWidth/2, SCREENHEIGHT/2-SCREENWIDTH/2, imageViewWidth, SCREENWIDTH);
        }else{

            rect = CGRectMake(0, SCREENHEIGHT/2-SCREENWIDTH/2, SCREENWIDTH, SCREENWIDTH);
        }
    }else{
            rect = CGRectMake(0, SCREENHEIGHT/2-SCREENWIDTH/2, SCREENWIDTH, SCREENWIDTH);
    }
    clipImage = [screenImage cropImage:screenImage inRect:rect];
    return clipImage;
}


+ (UIImage *) imageFromView:(UIView *)imageView {
    CGFloat scale = 1;
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] == YES)       {
    scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    }
    if (scale > 1) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, NO, scale);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, NO, 2);
    }

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [imageView.layer renderInContext: context];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return viewImage;
}


- (UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage*)image inRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    double (^rad)(double) = ^(double deg) {
        return deg / 180.0 * M_PI;
    };

CGAffineTransform rectTransform;
switch (image.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        rectTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad(90)), 0, -image.size.height);
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
        rectTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad(-90)), -image.size.width, 0);
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
        rectTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad(-180)), -image.size.width, -image.size.height);
        break;
    default:
        rectTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
};
rectTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(rectTransform, image.scale, image.scale);

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], CGRectApplyAffineTransform(rect, rectTransform));
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:image.scale orientation:image.imageOrientation];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);

return result;
```

}

Comment: I got part that imageview bounds changing when zooming. Just coldn't figure out how to calcute right.
So i tried your solution and here the deal it's doesn't cut right rect and it doesn't take in account scroll view offset, here are so examples
Here is 2 different visibles parts
[1](http://imgur.com/tJw6m8W)
[2](http://imgur.com/BCFPHGS)
in both cases i got this
[result](http://imgur.com/6hAW4CW)
and here is the same
[1](http://imgur.com/BAV2t1y)
[2](http://imgur.com/gta91ZR)
result
[result](http://imgur.com/BQToolS)
Also i don't understand what "type" variable is for.